# In-app Billing V3 Service nullpointer Android

Tags: java, android, service, binding

Currently I am experimenting with 'In-app Billing V3'. According to Google, I have to create a service, so I have done that, but I can't get bind.

This is my code:

Mainactivity:

```
Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND"),
                    mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

I also have this:

```
IInAppBillingService mService;

ServiceConnection mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {

     public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, 
              IBinder service) {

                System.out.println("Test!");
               mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
     }

     public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
       mService = null;
     }


};
```

And in my Manifest file I have this:

`<service android:name="com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService" />`

I am using http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html as source.

Comment: You mention a null pointer in the title. Can we see a logcat of that?

Comment: Yes, that's because I am using 'mService' but it's null. That's where the nullpointer comes from. 'onServiceConnected' is never called.

Comment: Did you get the example app to work?  TrivialDrive  It took me several tries, but I think if you skipped that exercise, it's worth going back to do it.

Comment: Did you get an answer on this one, I'm running into the same issue. I got it working the first purchase and ever after it gives a nullpointer.

Comment: See this link. Hopefully it will help you. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303772/why-am-i-getting-a-null-pointer-error-in-my-android-code

Comment: I too faced exactly the same problem. mService has to be accessed only after making sure execution of onServiceConnected() is finished. Otherwise, it would be null. You need to implement various listeners as is done in IabHelper.java of TrivialDrive example. See startSetup() and its onIabSetupFinishedListener argument  to get an idea. After I implemented as per the example, I never faced null mService!