# Why am I getting a null pointer error in my Android Code?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am getting a null point error in my code and the log is pointing here

```
199     public void getPurchasedSubs () throws RemoteException {
200         Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "subs", null);
```

Here is the logcat file dump

```
03-08 13:24:45.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7149): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-08 13:24:45.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7149): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.imobilize.ETV_V3_INAPP_SUB/com.imobilize.ETV_V3_INAPP_SUB.IntroBLevActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-08 13:24:45.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7149):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
03-08 13:24:45.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7149):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
03-08 13:24:45.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7149):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
03-08 13:24:45.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7149):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
03-08 13:24:45.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7149):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-08 13:24:45.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7149):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-08 13:24:45.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7149):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
03-08 13:24:45.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7149):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-08 13:24:45.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7149):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-08 13:24:45.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7149):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
03-08 13:24:45.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7149):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
03-08 13:24:45.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7149):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-08 13:24:45.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7149): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-08 13:24:45.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7149):     at com.imobilize.ETV_V3_INAPP_SUB.IntroBLevActivity.getPurchasedSubs(IntroBLevActivity.java:200)
03-08 13:24:45.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7149):     at com.imobilize.ETV_V3_INAPP_SUB.IntroBLevActivity.checkValidation(IntroBLevActivity.java:238)
03-08 13:24:45.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7149):     at com.imobilize.ETV_V3_INAPP_SUB.IntroBLevActivity.onCreate(IntroBLevActivity.java:96)
03-08 13:24:45.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7149):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
03-08 13:24:45.619: E/AndroidRuntime(7149):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
```

SPECS for this method

```
    /**
 * Returns the current SKUs owned by the user of the type and package name specified along with
 * purchase information and a signature of the data to be validated.
 * This will return all SKUs that have been purchased in V3 and managed items purchased using
 * V1 and V2 that have not been consumed.
 * @param apiVersion billing API version that the app is using
 * @param packageName package name of the calling app
 * @param type the type of the in-app items being requested
 *        ("inapp" for one-time purchases and "subs" for subscription).
 * @param continuationToken to be set as null for the first call, if the number of owned
 *        skus are too many, a continuationToken is returned in the response bundle.
 *        This method can be called again with the continuation token to get the next set of
 *        owned skus.
 * @return Bundle containing the following key-value pairs
 *         "RESPONSE_CODE" with int value, RESULT_OK(0) if success, other response codes on
 *              failure as listed above.
 *         "INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST" - StringArrayList containing the list of SKUs
 *         "INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST" - StringArrayList containing the purchase information
 *         "INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE_LIST"- StringArrayList containing the signatures
 *                                      of the purchase information
 *         "INAPP_CONTINUATION_TOKEN" - String containing a continuation token for the
 *                                      next set of in-app purchases. Only set if the
 *                                      user has more owned skus than the current list.
 */
Bundle getPurchases(int apiVersion, String packageName, String type, String continuationToken);
```

When I check for the package name it comes back valid

Here is the code where mService is created
        IInAppBillingService mService;

```
ServiceConnection mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
   //@Overide
       public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
       mService = null;
   }
       //@Overide
   public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, 
      IBinder service) {
       mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
   }

};
```

I am not that good at interpreting the logcat file, so the answer may be right in front of me.

This piece of code I thought was supposed to open it up so I coud use mService anytime.

```
        bindService(new 
            Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND"),
                    mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Comment: Have you tried using breakpoints and stepping through your code? It seems like mService is null when you try to call getPurchases().

Comment: Add logs to your onServiceDisconnected and see if its getting disconnected before you execute your code.

Also add null check before exception statement and logs to know if its null.

I suspect may be your service is not connected when you execute this code, or its getting disconnected by the time you execute this code

Comment: Which line causes the NPE? (ActivityThread.java:1970)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you use `mService` before connect to service.

My suggestion is to use boolean variable to check if activity connect to service or not,
or use `getPurchasedSubs ()` in `onServiceConnected` like this:

```
ServiceConnection mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
   public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
       mService = null;
   }

   public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, 
      IBinder service) {
       mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
getPurchasedSubs ();
   }

};
```

hope this helped you.

Comment: How do I make the get PurchasedSubs (); to be available anytime I need. I added a piece of my onCreate that was supposed to make this available but it doesn't and this is part of why it is not working

Comment: Also I get a weird error when dealing with the OVERIDE part of the MServiceeConn it says I need to remove it because must overide a superclass method so i removed it. Could that have a bad affect?

Comment: You can use PurchasedSubs (); any time you want, but must be after connected to service. Also you can put bindService(...); in onStart() to bind it before onCreate execute. See this link also [---link---](http://dharmendra4android.blogspot.com/2012/05/bind-service-using-ibinder-class.html)